# copy files from directory to destination recursively

Tags: php

i wrote a php script to copy all images from a directory "oldphoto", and then rename and move them for example logo.png -> into directory /l/o/logo.php

but finally the directory is successfully created, but the images are not copied, the following is the code

```
<?php

$objects = scandir('./oldphoto');


foreach ($objects as $value) {
    if ($value!='.' && $value!='..') {
        $prefix = renameTxt($value);
        moveImg ($prefix, $value);
    }

}

function renameTxt ($line) {
    $first_char = '/'.substr($line, 0 ,1);
    $sec_char = '/'.substr($line, 1 ,1).'/';
    $prefix = $first_char.$sec_char;
    return $prefix;

}

function moveImg ($prefix, $filename) {

    $src = $filename;
    $dst = '/newphoto'.$prefix;

    rcopy('oldphoto/'.$src, $dst, $filename);
}

function rcopy($src, $dst, $filename) {

    @mkdir('newphoto/'.$dst, 0, true);

    //echo $dst."<br>";
    echo $dst.$filename."<br>";
    echo 'src '.$src."<br>";
    echo 'filename '.$filename."<br>";  
    if (!copy($src, $dst.$filename)) {
        echo "fail to write image";
    }

}


?>
```

any one can figure out the problems?

echo results:

```
/newphoto/l/o/logo.png
src oldphoto/logo.png
/newphoto/l/o/logo_mini.png
src oldphoto/logo_mini.png
/newphoto/w/h/white50.png
src oldphoto/white50.png
```

Comment: Does the user running script have access to write to destination folder?

Comment: i run it on localhost + xampp + windows environment

Comment: but it can create directory.

Comment: Do you have a ending slash on $dst in your rcopy function? It might be trying to create a file named /l/ologo.php because it is missing that last slash.

Comment: ending slash is included

Comment: What is the results of your echos in rcopy?

Comment: /newphoto/l/o/logo.png
src oldphoto/logo.png
/newphoto/l/o/logo_mini.png
src oldphoto/logo_mini.png
/newphoto/w/h/white50.png
src oldphoto/white50.png

Comment: Looks like it is trying to make the folder in the root folder or in windows a invalid folder. Try to specify the exact location using __DIR__ or actually specifying the location.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: thanks, probelm fixed, the dst directory is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your destination is wrong. The slash at beginning causes it to look in the root directory not your directory. Either use **DIR** or specify the directory absolute path.